# How can I write to /cache/recovery/command in Android?

Tags: android, shell, recovery

maybe this is a silly question, but I am a beginner in Android and I'm trying to make a small bash script to wipe data on Android phones automatically. I read somewhere that if I write the "--wipe_data argument" in the "/cache/recovery/command" and then "adb reboot recovery" it will erase all user data. So the question is how to write to cache without root. I even tried with a rooted device but I got Permission Denied.

Thanks

Comment: How do you run your **bash** script?

Comment: Hopefully, you cannot do this without root, as if you could, it would be a potential attack vector.

Comment: @ChrisStratton force a user into accepting Device Admin for app and you have your attack vector. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a rooted device to do that. If you are using a CWM based recovery, you can try:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

echo "1" > /data/wipe
reboot recovery
```

Remember to chmod the script to execution permissions:

```
chmod 755 script.sh
```

Be careful. Some stock recovery - that ones which comes from factory - can brick you device if you try to wipe data like that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's a way to wipe all data through Device Admin Api.Take a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

If you want to perform a factory reset, that's it.

Comment: The underlying mechanisms in the device admin api do end up dropping the command file in cache and rebooting the device I'm pretty sure.